# Create DropDownList of my model Jobs and use it in CreateEmployeesViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

First of all, excuse me if my English isn't that good.

I'm kind of stuck with this. I want to create a list of jobs and be able to choose which position the employee is in through a dropdown list.

This would be the model I have of the jobs. This is the model that created the connection to the database I'm using.

```cs
public partial class jobs
{
    public jobs()
    {
        this.employees= new HashSet<employees>();
    }

    public int id_job { get; set; }
    public string job{ get; set; }//NameJob

    public virtual ICollection<employees> employees{ get; set; }
}
```

But as for the employee model I created a view model as follows.

```cs
public class CreateEmployeesViewModel
{
    [Required (ErrorMessage = "It is necessary to enter a name")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; } //Name

    [Required (ErrorMessage = "It is necessary to enter the Last Name ")]
    [Display(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LName{ get; set; } //LastName

    [Required (ErrorMessage = "What's your employee's job title?")]
    public int Job{ get; set; } //idjob
}
```

In my controller, I have the following

```cs
//Get Add
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}
```

And for the post

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(CreateEmployeesViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    using (var db = new DBExerciseEntities())
    {
        var emp = new employees();//New Employee
        emp.id_status = 1;//By default I set the new user as Active
        emp.name= model.Name;//Get Name
        emp.lname= model.LName;//get Last Name
        /*This is what I want to turn into DropDownList. Instead of typing the job "int" I want
         *to get the list of registered jobs*/
        emp.id_job = model.Job;//get id_job

        db.employees.Add(emp);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/CEmployees/"));
}
```

The view is as the following

```
@model Exercise.Models.ViewModels.CreateEmployeesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddUser";
}
    
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "CEmployees", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Error", new { @class = "text-danger", @type = "text" })
                        
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Name", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.LName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.LName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("LName", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            <!-- I get the name of the [display] assigned in the model-->
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.Job)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Job, new { @class = "form-control" })<!--How can I do DropDownList?-->
            <!-- mensajes de error  -->
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Job", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="AddUser" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

If you could help me it would be very helpful as those I have seen do so with static lists or are simply confusing.

I just want to mention that I'm relying on a different code to get what I have so far and I'm new to MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, don't use `ViewData` if you don't have to. Since a view model is in used, we just need to have another property in that view model to contain a list of available job titles.

#### The View Model

First, I would rename the model to just `CreateEmployeeViewModel` instead of CreateEmployee**s**ViewModel since you're creating just single employee at a time. And then I would rename some of the properties and remove some unnecessary data annotations:

```cs
public class CreateEmployeeViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "It is necessary to enter a name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; } //Name

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "It is necessary to enter the Last Name ")]
    [Display(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LName{ get; set; } //LastName

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "What's your employee's job title?")]
    public int SelectedJobId { get; set; } //idjob

    public IDictionary<int, string> AvailableJobs { get; set; }
}
```

Here I used `IDictionary` to contain the list of available job titles since you have only the id and name. If you have more than 2 properties you want to pass, you can create your own view model class for each available job option and use `IEnumerable` or `ICollection` instead.

#### Initialize View Model in Controller

Next, on the HttpGet Add action method, you need to fetch the list of available job titles from your database and load it up to the view model, and return it to the view:

```cs
public ActionResult Add()
{
    var vm = new CreateEmployeeViewModel
    {
        AvailableJobs = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    };

    using (var db = new DBExerciseEntities())
    {
        vm.AvailableJobs = db.jobs
            .ToDictionary(x => x.id_job, x => x.job);
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

#### The View

On the view you can use `@Html.DropdownListFor()` helper to generate the dropdown input for the `SelectedJobId`.

I've also changed your `@Html.ValidationMessage` to `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`.

By the way, I saw you used Bootstrap css classes. Come on! You can craft a better UI with that:

```
@model Exercise.Models.ViewModels.CreateEmployeeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddUser";
}
    
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "CEmployees", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Error", new { @class = "text-danger", @type = "text" })
                
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(d => d.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.Name, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(d => d.LName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.LName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.LName, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(d => d.SelectedJobId)
        @Html.DropdownListFor(d => d.SelectedJobId, 
            new SelectList(Model.AvailableJobs, "Key", "Value"), 
            new { @class = "form-control" }
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.SelectedJobId, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add User</button>
    </div>
}
```

The `SelectedJobId` should contain user's selection when the form posts back to the server.

Comment: Dude, I don't know how to thank you, I was already giving up, and about the CSS I use it because for the tests it was the fastest way hahahah but I do know that I can do better

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Here is my solution. Hope to help, my friend :))

1. First, you need to add 1 list jobs in  Add controller.

   ```
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstJobs = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Teacher", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Engineer", Value = "2" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Accountant", Value = "3" }
        };
        ViewData["job"] = lstJobs;
        return View();
    }
   ```
2. Then, show list job in View.

   ```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Employees", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Error", new { @class = "text-danger", @type = "text" })


            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Name", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.LName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.LName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("LName", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            <!-- I get the name of the [display] assigned in the model-->
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.Job)
            @Html.DropDownList("Job", ViewData["job"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Job, new { @class = "form-control" })*@
            <!-- mensajes de error  -->
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Job", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="AddUser" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
   ```

Finally, when you submit the form you will get Job value.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have seen several ways similar to the one you propose, but I never understood how to adapt it to what I was using, but I still appreciate that you took the trouble to respond to me.

Comment: @DiegoVargas: Sorry for using ViewData, my friend. I should use the property :))